# Integer value rounding in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have code as below:

```
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim num2 As Integer

num1 = 12.5
num2 = 17.5
```

When I output the values, I get this:

```
num1: 12
num2: 18
```

If `12.5` become `12`, is `17.5` supposed to be `17`?

Or if `17.5` become `18`, is `12.5` supposed to be `13`?

I'm pretty new in Visual Basic, and it's hard to find any reference on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `VB` use [**banker’s rounding (round-to-even rule)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) as stated in [Integer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx)

In this method, when the remainder at the rounding position is `.5`, that number is **rounded up** when the number before it **is odd**, and **rounded down** when the number before it **is even**.

For example, using round-to-even rule

```
2.5 round down to the even number 2.0, 
3.5 would round up to the even number 4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be assigning `Double` values to `Integer` variables anyway.  Whenever you rely on implicit conversions, you really shouldn't be surprised if things don't happen the way you want.  That said, even an explicit conversion, e.g. `CInt`, would do the same thing.

Check out the documentation for the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and particularly the overloads that take a `MidpointRounding` value.  That's how you control the way such values are rounded.

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default VB.NET rounds to the nearest even number. So 12.5 will be 12 and 17.5 is 18 as 17 is a odd number.